# Boolean algebra: What is the name of this rule.

Tags: terminology, boolean-algebra

What is the name of the rule that would be applied to get from here

> $$A\bar{B}+\bar{B}\bar{C}+\bar{A}C$$

to

> $$\bar{B}+\bar{A}C$$

The only 3 term rule I know of is the consensus rule

Comment: Are you looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws ?

Comment: No because I already broke all of the bars.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**
$$
A\bar{B} + \bar{B}\bar{C}
 = \bar{B}\left(A+\bar{C}\right)
 = \bar{B} \overline{\bar{A}C}
$$

Comment: I don't care about solving it, I just care about the name it goes by. For example the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_theorem

Comment: @JohnSmith Hi John! Welcome to Math SE! Hope you have a great time here. However I encourage you not to use phrases like *I don't care* here for getting a better response. It might happen that the person answering your question may not like it and may seem rude. You may read here-https://math.stackexchange.com/conduct . Happy SE-ing! ;-)